# Cannot instantiate class com.qtpselenium.zoho.project.testcases.Lead Test

Tags: selenium, ant

**My Build.xml as beolw**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE project []>

 <project name="Learning TestNG" default="usage" basedir=".">  

 <!-- ========== Initialize Properties ============================== -->
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Selenium Jars"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="testng-report-dir" value="${test.src}/TestNGreport" />

<!--target name="start-selenium-server">
    <java jar="${ws.home}/lib/selenium-server.jar"/>
</target-->

<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" 
        property="test.classpath" 
        refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>
    <path id="testcase.path">
    <pathelement location="${test.dest}"/>

    <fileset dir="${ws.jars}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
    </tstamp>
    <condition property="ANT" 
        value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat" 
        else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
                <os family="windows" />
    </condition>
    <taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
           classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
    </target>

<!-- all -->
<target name="all">
</target>
 <!-- clean -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
</target>

<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling..."/>
    <javac 
        debug="true" 
        destdir="${test.dest}" 
        srcdir="${test.src}" 

        classpath="${test.classpath}"
        includeantruntime="false" >
    </javac>
  </target>

<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>

<!-- run -->

 <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <testng classpath="${test.classpath}: ${test.dest}"
  suitename="SuiteName">
            <xmlfileset dir="src/test/resources/" includes="TestNG.xml"/>
        </testng>   
    </target>
  <target name="usage">
    <echo>
        ant run will execute the test
    </echo>
</target>

<path id="test.c">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

  <target name="makexsltreports">
        <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

        <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/test 

  /resources/testng-results.xsl" out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output  

  /index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
  <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports  

  /output/"/>
  <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
 </project>
```

**TestNG.xml is as below**

```
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 <suite name="SuiteName">

    <test name="Login Test" allow-return-values="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qtpselenium.zoho.project.testcases.LoginTest" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Lead Test" allow-return-values="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.qtpselenium.zoho.project.testcases.LeadTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

**Error displayed below**

```
 run:
```

[testng] [TestNG] [ERROR]

[testng] Cannot instantiate class com.qtpselenium.zoho.project.testcases.Lead
 Test
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds

what will be solution for this not getting route cause..please it will better as early as possible

Comment: It's resolved.  I redownloaded  all jars  by using command mvn compile

Comment: 1.mvn compile 2. mvn eclipse:eclipse  3. ant run  result : success